# cd: permission denied: /a/b/c/d, but can get to d by CDing one directory at a time

Tags: linux, bash, mount

I am occasionally running into this weird situation where I when I try to CD into a particular directory, it gives me a permission denied error. But when I CD into it one directory at time (i.e., CD /a, followed by CD b/, CD c/ and CD d/ it works and then I am able to CD using the full path also).

/a is a network mount and when I look at the mount points using mount command it does show that it is mounted. I suspect this something to do with the mount being idle? Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your logs show anything?

Comment: Is automount in use, and you need to 'step in' to the parent folder to trigger the mount? I've seen something similar a long time ago...